# Merge two DataFrames by column of sets

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Pandas DataFrames:

`df1`:

```
name_tokens
[havard, university, kennedy school, government]
[university, texas, austin]
[boston, college]
```

`df2`:

```
ranking    name_tokens
  1        [havard, university]
  2        [university, texas]
  3        [boston, college]
```

I would like to merge `df2` to `df1` by `name_tokens` to get `ranking`. Merging condition is:

```
(df1['name_tokens'] & df2['name_tokens']) == df2['name_tokens']
```

How should I customize my merge method to accomplish this? (I have millions of records in `df1`, and it can be many to one merge to `df2`, so a fast implementation is desirable).

Comment: If I understand correctly you just want ranking column for df1 which are in df2 correct? So for your condition, do he name_tokens match between df1 and 2?

Comment: Why is `'university'` repeated all over? What are you trying to do, just look up the ranks of schools? Label groups of schools with the same ranks? Give a more complete example.

Comment: @U2EF1: it might be `college`, `institute` etc. I would like to look up rank by "fuzzy matching" one user input school name with a standard ranking.

Comment: Okay, this data is a little messy for a dataframe, then. Because it seems like you could have a column `type` which will be "university", "college", or whatever. And a column `name`. In a traditional db, the other fields (that we don't have names for) might go in a dataframe of `(school_id int, tag string)`. Once you've separated out `name` and `type` getting the rank is a very simple join. I don't know if you have more complicated ideas in mind.

Comment: Do you want this? Procedure: Take example name_token list from df1: [university, texas, austin]. See if name_token list of df2 ([university, texas]) is INCLUDED in df1 (i.e. all elements of name_token of df2 are in the list of name_tokens of df1), then attach ranking to that row? Would you keep the name_tokens from df2 where they exist? If you can, please supply us with an expected output so we can be sure we are providing a solution for what you ask.